# how to check whether password field is encrypted

Tags: selenium-rc

how to check whether password field is encrypted with selenium. i meant that password field is masked and not displayed.

Comment: Do you mean hidden so that input is blanked by symbols?

Comment: This question needs some clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean masked, you should be able to assert that an input of type password exists on the page.